# "Crazy about" in formal English

Tags: expressions, formal-language

I'm writing a resume and I want to express how much I like something related to a professional sphere. The first draft contains a sentence "I am mad about ...". As resume must be more formal I want to change that line to its equivalent.

What's the way to say "I am crazy about doing something" on the edge of formal English and displaying my emotional intensity towards this thing?

Comment: Keep it simple. *I love doing something. I am passionate about it.*

Comment: Keep the "I am passionate about" for the covering letter.  The CV/Resume should be a fairly straightforward listing of your educations experience and skills.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace "I'm crazy about"/"I'm mad about" with

- I greatly enjoy ...
- I am passionate about ...